# "Uncaught reference" error in ES6 class when using `for of` in method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I was trying to use `for of` in one of my methods following ES6 syntax and run into `Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined.` Message is obvious and I've fixed it.

My question is why do we have to explicitly declare variable when using it for looping in the method, but not in global scope? And why if we use variable implicitly declared in global scope it can be used in class afterwards?

Example:

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

for(i of arr){
  console.log(i);
}

    class bar{
        constructor(arr){
            this.innerArr = arr;
        }
      // so how this one gets reference to outside i?
        yell(){
            for(i of this.innerArr){
                console.log(i);
            }
        } 
    }

    class baz extends bar{
      // in here it's obviously fine because we have var ii
        yell(){
            let ii
            for(ii of this.innerArr){
                console.log(ii);
            }
        } 
    }

    class foo extends bar{
      // This gives Uncaught ReferenceError
        yell(){
            for(item of this.innerArr){
                console.log(item);
            }
        } 
    }

    var br = new bar(arr);
    var bz = new baz(arr);
    var f = new foo(arr);

    br.yell();
    bz.yell();
    f.yell();
```

It just that it somehow feels counter intuitive.

Comment: When not running in `strict mode`, you are declaring an accidental global when you fail to declare the variable before using it.  This will work, but is extremely bug prone and never recommended.  ALWAYS declare your variables in the appropriate scope before using them.  And, run in `strict mode` where you are forced to declare all variables before use (to prevent subtle, accidental bugs).

Comment: So why can't inner method create that global variable? You pretty much explained what I've needed, just the last bit is still a bit unclear.

Comment: What environment are you running in?  I find no difference between top scope and inner scope in Chrome.  In strict mode, the `for/of` is not allowed unless you declare the variable name.  In non-strict mode, it auto-makes a global whether at top scope or lower scope.  See this example in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/w0r180b1/

Comment: It's chrome, not `strict`. Try the examples which I have given. `foo.yell` gives an error. But now it's even more confusing because it does work in function by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to `for of`. The [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code) states that

> All parts of a ClassDeclaration or a ClassExpression are strict mode code.

And in strict mode  you cannot access a variable that has not been declared yet.

As for why `bar.yell()` can access `i`: `i` is already declared as global variable because of this code:

```
for(i of arr){
  console.log(i);
}
```

That code runs in global scope in non-strict mode. Because of that `i` is automatically declared as global variable.

Comment: If you could expand the answer with the explanation of why `bar` can access the `i` then I will accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij Done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the variable in local scope, you must use the `let` keyword. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

The var keyword can be used and overwritten in global and local scope. I think this is because of the history of JavaScript.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question why we need to declare variable for `for of` in method but not in global, and how it manages to access the i from global scope. But thanks for `let`, cleared out some things.